# Axiom UB on Grothendieck Universes

Tags: set-theory

I am having problems understanding Grothendieck's second axiom on universes: In SGA it reads "Let $R\{x\}$ be a relation and ${\mathscr U}$ be a universe. If there exists $y\in{\mathscr U}$ such that $R\{y\}$, then $\tau_x R\{x\}\in{\mathscr U}$."

Can somebody tell me the definition of relation and of $\tau_x R\{x\}$ that's being used here?

It is used for example in order to establish for each ${\mathscr U}$-category ${\mathcal C}$ and any $x\in\text{Obj}({\mathcal C})$ the functor ${\mathcal C}(-,x): {\mathcal C}^{\text{op}}\to{\mathscr U}\text{-Set}$, which cannot be done naively as the morphism sets ${\mathcal C}(y,x)$ are only required to be *isomorphic* to ${\mathscr U}$-sets, not to be ${\mathscr U}$-sets themselves.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tau$ is the Hilbert choice operator. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177511/5191) for more details. For this axiom, an informal reading might go something like this:

> If $\phi (x)$ is a well-formed formula with a free variable $x$, and there exists an element $y$ in $\mathscr{U}$ such that $\phi (y)$ holds, then the canonical $x$ such that $\phi (x)$ holds is also in $\mathscr{U}$.

There is an alternative treatment of universes in the appendix of [SGA 4, Exposé I] that is based on ZFC-like set theory instead of Bourbaki set theory.

Comment: Thank you, Zhen! I didn't notice so far that it's not ZFC-like set theory that's used in SGA. Could you shortly explain what the correct replacement of the axiom (UB) in ZFC is?

Comment: There isn't one. ZFC does not have anything like $\tau$.

Comment: What does this mean concerning for example the definition of the representable functors ${\mathcal C}(-,x): {\mathcal C}^{\text{op}}\to{\mathscr U}\text{-Set}$? I don't see how one can define them in a canonical way. Does the lack of (UB) force one to restrict to categories whose morphism sets are actually ${\mathscr U}$-sets and not only isomorphic to those when working in the framework of ZFC? This would for example also restrict the possible size of the set of objects in a ${\mathscr U}$-category in that the latter has to be isomorphic to a subset of ${\mathscr U}$?

Comment: You should go look at the appendix in [SGA 4, Exposé I]. In ZFC, one can prove that any category whose hom-sets are isomorphic to sets in $\mathscr{U}$ is in fact isomorphic as a category to one whose hom-sets _are_ in $\mathscr{U}$, so there is no loss of generality in restricting attention to those. The lack of canonicity is just something one has to live with when there is no global choice operator.

Comment: Thank you, Zhen, I will have a look at the Expose! However, don't you need to assume that the set of objects of the category under consideration is isomorphic to a subset of ${\mathscr U}$ in order to make the category isomorphic to a category where the morphism sets are ${\mathscr U}$-sets (since the set of objects embeds into the set of morphisms)?

Comment: It depends on your definition of category. If you require the hom-sets to be disjoint, then yes. But then you will see the same phenomenon whether you use Bourbaki set theory or ZFC set theory.